# Proper way to retrieve data from sessionStorage in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to implement a code like this however i am getting an error as expected 
does anybody have any other way to do this or solve my error and make the code work. I have read that this can be done with AJAX but my teacher has forbidden me from using a language other than PHP javascript and html.

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php
 $user = "<script language='JavaScript'>var n=sessionStorage.getItem('user');document.write(n);</script>";

   //do something with $user
  ?>
  </body
  </html>
```

Comment: You're clearly confused about the differences between client side and server side programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not retrieve sessionStorage or localStorage data (that exists on client) on server (PHP in you example).
You have several options:

- store data in cookies which can be retrieved on server side
- send data via get http request (careful: URL limit size):
- send data via post http request and hidden form field
- and probably the best option, send data to server with AJAX.